# The SOAP payload exceeds the configured size limit of the server

Tags: rest, http, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have simple, basic proxy in wso2 esb 4.8.1, where I send input message to my endpoint and show the result.

```
XML => Endpoint => XML
```

My endpoint receives only SOAP (soap envelope, body) messages with specific SOAPAction, so I set

```
<property name="SOAPAction" value="MY VALUE" scope="transport"/>
```

before send and I know that this is set properly.
After send my message I get this error

```
SOAP-ENV:Client.PayloadSize
The SOAP payload exceeds the configured size limit of the server!
```

I don't know why, because when I send this message by restClient I receive results.

To eliminate input error I set PayloadFactory and set message (I'm sure that this message is ok) and I get the same error.

Piece of my send code:

```
  <property name="Content-Type"
               value="text/xml"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
 <property name="SOAPAction" value="MY VALUE" scope="transport"/>
 <send>
    <endpoint>
       <http method="POST"
             uri-template="http:address"/>
    </endpoint>
 </send>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 06.10.2015**

ESB logs shows this error:

```
Received an internal server error : Internal Server Error For : MY_ADDRESS For Request : Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:2fa54584-6165-4abc-bf7e-b33679aa1ef9] [Status Completed : true] [Status SendingCompleted : true] {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientHandler}
To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:2fa54584-6165-4abc-bf7e-b33679aa1ef9, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.PayloadSize</faultcode><faultstring>The SOAP payload exceeds the configured size limit of the server!</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

I read on this site 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp
that this is Client problem, but as I wrote earlier when I do CTR+C and CTR+V this payload message and put it to restClinet I get result.
Maybe ESB add something strange and send it?

**SECOND UPDATE 06.10.2015**

I turned on DEBUG mode and get this:

```
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "POST MY_SERVICE HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "SOAPAction: MY_URI[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Host: MY-HOST[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "User-Agent: Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "4d4[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "   <SOAP-ENV:Body>[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
                                                            MY_MESSAGE HERE
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "   </SOAP-ENV:Body>[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Content-Length: 342[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 11:42:30 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.PayloadSize</faultcode><faultstring>The SOAP payload exceeds the configured size limit of the server!</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire
```

}

I don't know why there is **"4d4"** before my message and **"0"** after it. Moreover there is **"[\r][\n]"** before and after. Is it wrong?

Comment: Where can you see this message (SOAP-ENV:Client.PayloadSize), in ESB logs or in your service endpoint logs ? If it's in ESB logs, this message is generated before send, or when the response is received, or this is in the SOAP Fault ?

Comment: I update my question and added ESB error.

Comment: You can use tcpmon or enable wire logs (in log4j.properties : log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG) to see what ESB send to your service

Comment: I update my question and added ESB DEBUG mode info.

Comment: When I add this  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" /> it works.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with "Microsoft-IIS" and it needed DISABLE_CHUNKING. I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: In your logs, I can see "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" but the packet size is huge (4D4 = 1236) I was looking for a way to specify this size, but you can disable chunking ;-)